# Why does this regex take lot of time?^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9][-][^\s._^%$#!~@,])+$

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

This regex takes lot of time to match any string.

String to Match `cbdvhuvffviuhwrevfnvfduvildouqjiofeqfelvimpupvcuipvhfjdvufhvfd,ofvhfuhffduisfdwfewdsiu`

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*[-]*[^\s._^%$#!~@,])+$
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com) stops working.

Comment: This is a case of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks. Please post it as answer. I ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regular Expressions can be very expensive. Certain (unintended and intended) strings may cause RegExes to exhibit exponential behavior.
>
> -- (from [CodingHorror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/))

So called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) can occur when you have two nested groups of variable matches which can match the same thing in your regular expression.

Especially if the inout doesn't match the regex, engine will check all combinations of the groups in a nested loop which can take quite some time.

Basically, a regex engine will always try to match as many characters as it can with each step, even with variable groups (i.e. sequences with `+`, `*`, or `?`). If at some point, it reaches a situation where either the input string ended without the regex having fully matched or a situation occurs where no more characters can match the current group, the engine will backtrack. That means, it will "unmatch" a character and try to find a solution where only the next variable group matches that.

Now, in your regular expression, you have a nested variable group. In this case, the engine can run into a deeply nested loop trying to find a matching combination. This can take a very long time and can thus sometimes be used as a DoS vector.

Regular expression engines are not very smart and work by very simple rules (see [Regular Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) on Wikipedia). As such they typically will not detect these loops themselves and will happily work along, trying all the combinations.

> The solution is simple. When nesting repetition operators, **make absolutely sure that there is only one way to match the same match.** If repeating the inner loop 4 times and the outer loop 7 times results in the same overall match as repeating the inner loop 6 times and the outer loop 2 times, you can be sure that the regex engine will try all those combinations.